# I am using a IF condition to select the element getting error as no such element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In the below code i am getting error as no such element but when i try with out if condition its working fine

String currenturl= driver.getCurrentUrl();
String UK="gben",NZ="nzen",SE="sesv",AU="auen",NL="nlnl",NO="nonb",IE="ieen",DK="dkda",FI="fifi";
if (currenturl.contains("NL||NO||IE||DK||FI||SE")) {
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-bbb-glasses > a")).click();
} else if(currenturl.contains("NZ||UK")) {
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-glasses > a")).click();
} else {
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ss-nav-primary__item--menu-new-test > a")).click();
}

Comment: Is that the same element that worked without the if and that is involved with if-else here? Are you sure?

Comment: yes sure it worked with out if  condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is wrong.
Instead of

```
if (currenturl.contains("NL||NO||IE||DK||FI||SE"))
```

it should be

```
if(currenturl.contains(NL) || currenturl.contains(NO) || currenturl.contains(IE) || currenturl.contains(DK) || currenturl.contains(FI) || currenturl.contains(SE))
```

The same is about the rest